# omp parallel doesn't give any performance increase for matrix multiplication

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, openmp, concurrent-programming, shared-resource

I'm using following 2 code blocks to compute matrix multiplication serially and parallel.

Serial -

```
double** ary1 = new double*[in];
double** ary2 = new double*[in];
double** result = new double*[in];
for (int i=0;i<in;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<in;j++){
        result[i][j] = 0;
        for(int k = 0;k<in; k++){
            result[i][j] += ary1[i][k]*ary2[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Parallel -

```
double** ary1 = new double*[in];
double** ary2 = new double*[in];
double** resultsP = new double*[in];
#pragma omp parallel for 
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
  int raw = i/in;
  int column = i%in;
  double sum =0;
  for(int k = 0; k < in; k++){
       resultsP[raw][column] += ary1[raw][k]*ary2[k][column];
  }
  resultsP[raw][column] = sum;
}
```

I ran both in quad-core computer, but get same results.
Why I don't get performance increased by running this parrellely?
Does accessing ary1, ary2, resultsP shared arrays inside parellel loop cause them to run serially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened since '-fopenmp' flag hasn't included when compiling the code. Problem was solved by adding it.

Comment: To prevent errors of this sort from cropping up in the future, I'd recommend compiling with the `-Wall` flag, which will display some previously hidden compiler warnings such as unknown `#pragma`s.

Comment: Will you gain performance even if you used AVX for the Multiplication? My question is, does element wise multiplication using AVX is memory bounded?